# Defining Typescript types for CommonJS module

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make [xmllint](https://github.com/kripken/xml.js) work with Typescript.

Since it is traditional JS, importing the module directly in Typescript will show a compile error

```
Cannot find module 'xmllint' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

So I created a file `index.d.ts` in my root folder :

```
declare module 'xmllint'{
    export interface ValidationResult{
        errors: string[]
    };
    export interface Options{
        xml: string, xsd:string
    }
    export function validateXML(opts: Options): ValidationResult;
}
```

Now this compiles. But no matter what I try, I cannot import that module inside a Typescript class. It will always either return an empty object or `undefined`.

I tried

- `import {validateXML} from "xmllint"`, then validateXML is an empty object
- `import validateXML from "xmllint"`, then validateXML is undefined
- `import * as validate from "xmllint"`, then validateXML is an empty object

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I feel like this is because my `index.d.ts` is not pointing to the native function of xmllint, but I have no idea how to do that properly.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's your Tsconfig

Comment: I just notice that it has a [TS bind version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmllint-ts) although it seems like not maintain for a long time, maybe try [another fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmllint-wasm)?

Comment: @kelsny I included the tsconfig file. Thanks for the links, I'll give it a try, but I wanted also to check why this would not work, maybe someday I'll actually have to do that.

Comment: Consider updating to a newer *fork* of that package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmllint-wasm

Comment: @Dimava my goal is to do a client-side (browser) XSD validation, and xmllint-wasm doesn't seem to fully support browser usage. I kind of realized my original issue was probably linked to the underlying library being broken. The typescript definitions worked since the beginning, it's just that the library is not working in the browser. Thanks for the pointer though, I'll fallback on this if I need to.

Comment: Maybe you should find another modern solution instead of using this very old package, which is no longer updated and whose package build script is hard to understand. BTW, I spent some time reading its source code. https://github.com/kripken/xml.js/blob/master/script/compile#L3-L11

Comment: https://syssgx.github.io/xml.js/js/xmllint.js
This demo is not exported the `xmllint`.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiSag.png

Answer (score 0):

The `xmllint` package is a CommonJS default export, i.e., `module.exports = xmllint`, where `xmllint` is an object with `validateXML` property as a function. So, your type should be something like this -

```ts
declare module "xmllint" {
  export interface ValidationResult {
    errors: string[];
  }

  type Options = { xml: Array<string>; xsd: Array<string> };

  type XMLLint = {
    validateXML(options: Options): ValidationResult;
  };

  const xmllint: XMLLint;

  export default xmllint;
}
```

Once added, you'll need to make sure that the Typescript is able to detect it by adding an entry to `tsconfig.json`. Once added, you can use it by importing it like so -

```ts
import fs from "node:fs";
import xmllint from "xmllint";

const xml = fs.readFileSync("./src/test.xml").toString();
const schema = fs.readFileSync("./src/test.xsd").toString();

console.log(xmllint.validateXML({ xml: [xml, xml], xsd: [schema, schema] }));
```

Which resulted in the following output for the test files from the package itself -

```ts
{
  errors: [
    "file_0.xsd:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found",
    'undefined',
    '^',
    "Schemas parser error : Failed to parse the XML resource 'file_0.xsd'."
  ]
}
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/node-ts-playground-forked-x698dj?welcome=true).

P.S - Note that the type errors in the Codesandbox are there because of the environment, you shouldn't get these in an IDE like vs code.